# Mysql count performance on very big rows between two dates conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, count, query-optimization, database-performance

I have a table with more than 20 million rows in Innodb.

the columns are

```
id, viewable_id, visitor, viewed_at
```

where the `viewable_id` and `viewed_at` are indexes.
when I do the below query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM views_users 
WHERE (viewable_id = 2) 
  and (viewed_at between '2021-04-19 01:38:37' 
  and '2021-06-30 01:38:37');
```

> => take (3 min 6.72 sec)

the explain is

```
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type | possible_keys                                             | key                           | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------+-------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | views_users | NULL       | ref  | views_users_viewable_id_index,views_users_viewed_at_index | views_users_viewable_id_index | 8       | const | 9554594 |    50.00 | Using where
```

How can I increase the performance to reach less than 4 seconds?

```
CREATE TABLE views_users (
    id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    viewable_type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    viewable_id bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
    visitor text,
    collection varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    viewed_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY user_id (viewable_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20995848
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE views_users`.

Comment: @RickJames views_users | CREATE TABLE `views_users` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `viewable_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `viewable_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `visitor` text,
  `collection` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `viewed_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`viewable_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20995848 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Comment: What does the `COUNT(*)` return?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I increase the performance to take less than 2 seconds by applying [MySQL partiotons](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-partitioning-excerpt/8.0/en/partitioning-types.html).

I used partition by range using the `viewed_at` column. change `viewed_at` type from `timestamp` to `datatime` and made it as primary key with `id`.
make a cronjob runs on first day of each month that reorganize last partition into another partitions and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM views_users
WHERE viewable_id = 2 and
      viewed_at between '2021-04-19 01:38:37' and '2021-06-30 01:38:37';
```

You can create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_views_users_viewable_id_viewed_at ON views_users(viewable_id, viewed_at);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this. it takes (2 min 36.57 sec).

Comment: @AmrAbdalrahman . . . Do you have the specified index?  How large is the result?

Comment: yes , views_users_viewable_id_viewed_at is 50560 
views_users_viewable_id_viewed_at is 4804695